# Speed up a search for Carmichael numbers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, primes

The main question here is: is there a better way that using "all" in Python?
I have read that it goes through every condition and then comes back to see if any are true. I want to check one condition at a time and then quit as soon as one doesn't work. I believe this is called "Short Circuit.....". I can't use a series of "and"s because they change by input and there could be millions of conditions.

I'm looking for [Carmichael numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_number). One definition for a Carmichael Number is that b^n = b (mod n) for all 1 < b < n. If a number n fails the test then it's composite. If it passes the test it may be either prime or Carmichael. I then checked if it was prime or not.

I used the code:

```
def Carm(num):
    if all(gcd(k,num) == 1 for k in range(3,int(round(num**0.5)),2)) and gcd(2,num) == 1:
        print(num,'is a Prime Number')
    elif all(pow(b,num,num)==b for b in range(1,num)) and gcd(num,2)==1:
        print(num,'is a Carmichael Number')
    else:
        print(num,'is not a Carmichael Number')
```

Comment: For one, I would reverse the order of your conditions. `and` short circuits: if the first condition is `False`, it doesn't check the second. If one of your conditions is drastically slower than the other, it should come last.

Comment: Also, can you post your code for `gcd()`?

Comment: Thank you very much for replying! Which conditions should I swap? Could you please suggest the best order?

The gcd is imported from "fractions": `from fractions import gcd`

Comment: Why would you go through all the effort of a full GCD computation just to check divisibility?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Answer to original question

The best I was able to get was about a 4.5x speedup by rearranging your conditions (speed up will depend on whether the number you input passes the first condition) and using `math.gcd()` in place of `fractions.gcd()`.

I also made them return a string rather than print one. This should be faster, but mostly I did it because it makes it easier to test timing. You can then do whatever you want with the string:

```
def carm_math_reorder(num):
    if math.gcd(2,num) == 1 and all(math.gcd(k,num) == 1 for k in
                                    range(3, int(round(num**0.5)), 2)):
        return 'Prime'
    elif math.gcd(num, 2) == 1 and all(pow(b, num, num)==b for b in
                                       range(1, num)):
        return 'Carmichael'
    return 'Composite'  # implicit "else" return

% timeit [Carm(num) for num in range(1000)]  # your implementation
16.9 ms ± 89.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

% timeit [carm_math_reorder(num) for num in range(1000)]
3.71 ms ± 45.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Rearranging the conditions works because `and` short-circuits (so does `all`, actually), so if the first condition doesn't pass, Python will ignore the second condition and just move on. In your case Carmichael test, the condition that checks a single `gcd()` is faster than the condition that checks `pow(b, n, n) == 1`, at least in my testing. Thus the `gcd()` test should go first. It probably doesn't matter for the line that tests if the number is prime. In my tests, this change resulted in about a 2x speedup.

I got warnings that `fractions.gcd()` was deprecated, so I went with `math.gcd()` instead, which was faster to boot! That got me the rest of the speedup seen.

Of course if you need to check a *lot* of numbers at once, you would probably be better off using `numpy` and vectorizing this. Let me know if that is your use case and I will see if I can think up a nice optimized version for that.

### Corrected Carmichael test

I am pretty sure that your check for Carmichael numbers was off. A number is Carmichael if `pow(b, n) % n == 1` *for all integers* `b`, not for all `b < n`. You can't check it this way, so you need a different rule.

It looks like you can use the fact that a number is Carmichael if `pow(b, n-1) % n == 1` for all `b = 1, 2, ..., n` such that `b` and `n` are co-prime. [Here is a good example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/carmichael-numbers/), and the code from said example (more or less):

```
from math import gcd
def is_carm(n):
    """ Check whether n is a Carmichael number """
    for b in range(2, n):
        # If b is relatively prime to n
        if gcd(b, n) == 1:
            # If pow(b, n-1) % n is not 1, not Carmichael
            if pow(b, n-1, n) != 1:
                return False
    return True  # Carmichael!
```

This is slower than the options above, but I believe it is technically correct: the best kind of correct.

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you!!! An alternative definition is that pow(b,n-1,n)=1 for all b<n with gcd(b,n)=1. Which do you think would be faster: (1) check pow(b,n,n)=b for all b<n and have no gcd check or (2) just check pow(b,n-1,n)=1 for all b with gcd(b,n)=1 and have to run a gcd check on every b??? (I chose the former because it's easier to program.)

Comment: I believe your first check is incorrect. At least [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_number), `pow(b, n, n) = 1` for *all integers* `b`, not all integers `b < n`! That's impossible to check in code. I think you have to check using [Korslet's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_number#Korselt's_criterion), but I don't even know what `p-1 | n-1` *means*...

Comment: I just updated the answer with something that I believe is more correct. I'm pretty sure the original checks were flawed.

Answer (score 1):

`all` already short circuits. Whatever source made you think it doesn't, either that source is wrong, or you misunderstood it. We can't tell.

It's still easily possible to speed this up, though. For example, your `gcd` calls are testing whether `num` is coprime to all those numbers, but this is expensive and unnecessary. We only need to check divisibility, which can be done with a much faster `num % k != 0`. Also, divisibility by 2 rules out many more numbers than any of the other checks, so putting that first will save some work. Also, the `gcd(num,2)==1` check in the `elif` is superfluous.

```
def is_carmichael(n):
    # Requires a positive integer.
    if n == 1:
        return '1'
    elif n % 2 != 0 and all(n % k != 0 for k in range(3, math.ceil(n**0.5), 2)):
        return 'prime'
    elif all(pow(k, n, n) == k for k in range(1, n)):
        return 'carmichael'
    else:
        return 'non-carmichael composite'
```